# What is the difference between ttyS0, ttyUSB0 and ttyAMA0 in Linux?

Tags: linux, tty

I want to know the difference between `ttyS0`, `ttyUSB0` and `ttyAMA0` on Linux.

Comment: You can look up many device types in the kernel docs: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devices.txt

Comment: Link in comment above is dead but I believe this is the updated path: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.rst

Answer (score 39):

### ttyS0

What you get on the host when you connect to target with this:

[image]

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port)

This port is not present on most laptops or small devboards, but is still present on many desktops, and is very convenient for OS developers as mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104771/where-are-kernel-panic-logs/932380#932380

You also get it with `qemu -device isa-serial`.

For example could hook up two desktops with one of those cables, and communicate directly between them to get a shell on the remote desktop from your own. From Linux computer 1 you would run:

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 115200
```

and then computer 2 would reply with the login prompt, and then you can log in from computer 1 into computer 2.

So this is a bit like SSH and can be seen as an early form of networking. I think those cables cannot be too long or else the signal is lost though, and you can't do as much without the TCP/IP addressing/packet mechanisms.

### ttyUSB0

What you get on host when using something like:

[image]

I also get it when I connect the GPIOs of my Raspberry Pi to my laptop [to get a shell on a Raspberry Pi without a screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14611/how-to-set-up-raspberry-pi-without-a-monitor/54393#54393)!

[image]

And another more integrated RPI connector version of the above:

[image]

[Source](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/3274/products/100267_1024x1024.jpg?v=1477646156)

A concrete RPI example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545

### ttyACM0

This is the TTY interface that what you get when you connect your computer to either of:

- [BBC micro:bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Bit) v1
- [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-pico/)

via an USB cable. They've just implemented a TTY directly on the same USB that can power on and program the device, it is very convenient!

[image]

### ttyAMA0

Haven't used this one on a real board yet.

It seems that I would be able to connect my desktop with a serial port to my RPI with that interface: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69697/what-is-dev-ttyama0

I've used it with QEMU: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/27d7ef126bc7f4eb1a757128466befa11245bbfd/board/qemu/arm-versatile

It seem that AMA is a shortened form of [AMBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture)? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8075 But why would they shorten a 4 character acronym?!

The only interesting Linux kernel hits are under: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/drivers/tty/serial/amba-pl011.c#L2488 so it seems to be strictly linked to the PL011: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0183g/index.html which is a UART controller licensed by ARM, which I think is the dominating implementation.

### ttySAC0

[Kamil reported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307390/what-is-the-difference-between-ttys0-ttyusb0-and-ttyama0-in-linux/367882?noredirect=1#comment878031_367882) that his [Samsung Artik 710](https://www.artik.io/modules/artik-710/), so another one for the collection.

Comment: What about ttySAC0? I have this on ARM64 architecture Samsung Artik 710 device.

Comment: @Kamil OK, a new one for me then :-) How do you connect to it from host to see `ttySAC0`? Which cable? Send a photo if you can.

Comment: I get a ttyACM0 when I plug in an Arduino into Linux.

Comment: Technically, `ttyS0`'s original meaning seems to be "the first serial port *implemented using a UART compatible with the original IBM PC UART, the 8250 chip*. The `ttyAMA0` on ARM and e.g. `ttySAC0` would then mean "the first serial port implemented using another specific hardware implementation". `ttyUSB0` refers to the first USB-to-serial converter. `ttyACM0` refers to an emulated serial connection using USB's CDC ACM (Communication Device Class, Abstract Control Model), which indicates that no actual RS-232-style serial line may be present and HW parameters like baud rate may be ignored.

Answer (score 20):

- `ttyS0` is the device for the first UART serial port on x86 and x86_64 architectures.  If you have a PC motherboard with serial ports you'd be using a `ttySn` to attach a modem or a serial console.
- `ttyUSB0` is the device for the first USB serial convertor.  If you have an [USB serial cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+serial+cable) you'd be using a `ttyUSBn` to connect to the serial port of a router.
- `ttyAMA0` is the device for the first serial port on ARM architecture.  If you have an ARM-based TV box with a serial console and running Android or OpenELEC, you'd be using a `ttyAMAn` to attach a console to it.

Comment: There's more at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127260/5132 .

Comment: are these 3 distinct serial port you can read from each one separately at the same time? and attach 3 different device 1 to each of these?