# Trying to enable instantiated service via debian package install

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd

I have an in-house config deb that I'm installing on a system. Among other things, I'd like to the package to enable a serial console, as described in http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html.

Appreciating that I could just run `systemd enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service` in my package's postinst, it feels like it would be better to leverage debhelper in order to ensure proper upgrade/uninstall behaviour. However, I'm finding that:

- I can't just call `dh_systemd_enable` from my `rules` file with the name of an instance unit; it expects to be pointed at an actual file (same thing if I do an end run and try to call `deb-systemd-helper` directly).
- I can install a target unit with debhelper, but I don't see to be able to make it do the right thing.

Here's what my target unit looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Serial Console

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
Requires=serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

I can enable and/or start this, and it shows as running under `systemctl status`, however it doesn't start the instance service which it is supposed to require.

So I guess my question is in two parts: first, why isn't my target unit working as expected, and second, is there a best way to achieve this under Debian packaging?

Comment: Presumably you do not want to just tell the kernel that the serial device is a console.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447098/5132  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248313/5132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `Requires` directive should appear in the `[Unit]` section, not in `[Install]`.
2. But instead ship a `/lib/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyS0.service -> /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` symlink in your package. First I assumed that `serial-getty@ttyS0.service` is automatically pulled in by `getty.target` if it exists, but such a dependency is only added by `systemd-getty-generator` for the main kernel console if it's a serial device, which is not the case here. See http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html and `man systemd-getty-generator` for further details.

Comment: Can confirm that it works as expected when I install the symlink to the `getty.target.wants` directory.