# How does systemd disable kernel console logging when starting getty?

Tags: linux, systemd, serial-console

I have noticed that if I have a kernel serial debugging enabled (and I see all the lovely kernel log lines printing out to the console), if I `systemctl start getty@ttyS0` the screen is cleared and further logs are suppressed.

I poked around and couldn't figure out the mechanism that systmed does to disable the kernel printing.  It's more than just setting proc/sys/printk to zero.

Anyone know?

Comment: Be aware that you are using the wrong service.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475043/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479911/5132

Comment: do you happen to know what the significant difference is?  I understand one is for virtual console vs physical console, but what are the relevant differences?  Is it just configuring baud rate?