# redhat kernel dump investigate

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, core-dump, dump

I have received a vmcore.gz (400MB) and vmcore-dmesg.txt file from production machine that had kernel panic.
The producation is redhat 5 machine with kernel 2.6.18-431.el5
In order to investigate the dump, I understand I need the same machine + kernel as the machine the kernel panic occur, I have an VM of redhat 5, but its not activated and i cannot download the exact kernel, I have kernel 2.6.18-92.el5.

Can i still get information on the dump ? at least the callstack/stack trace of the kernel when crashed ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to be running the same kernel necessarily, but logs from the crashed system would be helpful.  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60928/34505).

Comment: do use crash on my dump, i need vmlinux, to get vmlinux in my machine, i need to install kernel-debuginfo, is that right ?